# Nvme SSD not showing up after sudden black screen

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, nvme

I use dual boot windows 10 / Ubuntu 18.04 both on one ssd. One day I was working on Ubuntu and suddenly a black screen with lots of text started showing up exts-fs error something like that. I went one for like 20 mins repeating the same thing. So I force shutdown my laptop using the power button. But alas the next time I went on to boot my laptop it was stuck at Acer logo for 20-30 seconds then said no bootable device.

Then I went to bios and checked that there were no Nvme drives.

Things I did :

I used a live usb stick to boot into Ubuntu but gparted does not see the ssd. I checked dmesg status and was surprised to see that it said nvme0 : device not ready. Probe failed error status -19. 
I also checked lspci. It also deteted nvme disk as SK hynix Device 1327.